# Why do we feel negative G-forces in a high speed descent in a pressurized aircraft cabin?

Tags: g-forces

Could different momentums affect g-forces differently?

The way I see it, as an object accelerates, G-forces begin to be produced. As speed increases continuously, G-forces increase. When speed is constant (at any speed), no g-forces are created.

Am I looking at this correctly? What is not right, and what am I missing?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118170/discussion-on-question-by-thomas-why-do-we-feel-negative-g-forces-in-a-high-spee).

Answer (score 5):

There are two misconceptions here, lets sort them out first:

- pressurization has absolutely no effect on G -forces. For any maneuver they will be exactly the same, wheter you are in a pressurized, unpressurized, or even an open cockpit or passenger compartment.
- G forces other than the normal G can only be felt (or registered) when there is a change in the trajectory of a plane (or any object), and only during the change

So: when beginning a descent, the plane's trajectory must be changed by pointing the nose down (well this is a simplification, but lets just go with that). For the brief moment it takes for the plane to reach a steady descending speed, a reduced G can be observed. As soon as the descending speed becomes steady, the G-force is back to normal.

What a passenger might interpret as negative/reduced G, is the effect of the vector of gravity pointing slightly forward, as the plane's nose is pointed down, so "the seat of the pants" is telling us there's something fishy going on.

The difference to simply sitting on a chair tilted forward is that in a descending plane the whole close proximity surroundings are also tilted, making the brains think things are level when they actually are not. As the brains are accustomed to "calculating" G forces as always pointing straight down, input from your body computes the G force being less than normal.

Comment: It’s probably worth noting them at “G forces” in most cases (and most definitely here) have nothing to do with gravity, only acceleration. They are just expressed in terms of gravity because that’s something people can more easily relate to.

Comment: Yes. 1 G is the gold standard of how much the crust of the earth resists us and the earth from merging 

Answer (score 2):

Einstein developed his theory of General Relativity based on the principle that inertial mass and gravitational mass are one and the same thing. When your plane accelerates, you therefore feel a G force according to the Newtonian equation F = ma.

If you want to understand more about the consequences of Einstein's principle and why we all accept it, you will need to get to grips with tensor calculus, Minkowski space and curved spacetime.

Comment: Oh man you jumped straight into the deep end 

Comment: @Jpe61 How deep is "because it is accelerating"?

Comment: Oh not that, dropping in Minkowski space and tensor calculus is. Even Einsteind had trouble with tensors 

Comment: @Thomas check this out for a crash course on Albert's and Isaac's ideas on stuff: https://youtu.be/AwhKZ3fd9JA

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that we do NOT (under "normal" conditions) experience negative G forces in a descent.  The speed makes no difference, nor does pressurization.

There are some excellent answers already, but I would like to offer my perspective to help ensure complete understanding.  Let’s keep it simple, and discuss only 1G, 0G, and -1G.  And let’s keep it earth bound to start.

**1G Surface:**  Everyone alive knows what this feels like, it is the force of gravity from the earth.  Our entire physiology is adapted for life at 1G.

**0G Surface:**  This is weightlessness.  We only sort of experience this swimming in the water, or jumping off something high.  In the water, your natural buoyancy simulates zero gravity, but it doesn’t have a good comparison in the air so let’s ignore this example.  When you jump off something high, however, your body will begin to accelerate downward at 32ft/sec squared.  Because this free fall acceleration rate effectively cancels out the 1G feeling you get when the earth opposes your motion, you experience this weightless acceleration as zero Gs.  (This is relevant to flying, which I will get to...)

**-1G Surface:**  There really isn’t such a thing as negative G force on the surface because the earth doesn’t repel you, but when you hang upside down your body will experience the effect as negative 1G because gravity is acting opposite to the normal orientation of your body’s vertical axis.  Because we are adapted to having the force of gravity pulling towards our feet, the blood will rush to your head, and breathing and swallowing will become more difficult.  If you have never hung upside down from a tree branch as a kid, try it.  This is what -1G feels like.

Now let’s consider these same three examples in the context of what our bodies experience while airborne.  To keep things simple, let’s disregard high performance aerobatic airplanes and military jets, and focus only on “normal” passenger flights.  Our starting point is upright straight and level flight, (balanced unaccelerated) flight.

**1G Airborne:**  This is what you normally feel as a passenger in smooth air when all forces on the aircraft are in equilibrium.  You will also feel 1G in a climb or a descent because the forces are in equilibrium, just like you will feel 1G in your car whether you are driving up or down a hill.  You will only feel a momentary very slight increase in G when beginning a climb, or a slight decrease when initiating a descent, then it will even out.

**0G Airborne:**  Presuming your starting point is straight and level flight, (i.e. not trying to fly a parabolic arc) if you experience zero G airborne it is because you are accelerating towards the earth at the speed of a free falling object.  Quite literally, falling like a rock.  This can be accomplished by a pretty aggressive push forward on the controls, but can only be sustained by any airplane for a few seconds until reaching an extreme nose low position and exceeding the airspeed limit of the aircraft.  Beverages and food would "float" up in the air, and your whole body would feel weightless in the seat.  So, it shouldn’t be difficult to realize that passengers don’t experience sustained zero G in normal flight.

**-1G Airborne:**  While I specifically excluded aerobatic aircraft, it is worth noting that if you are flying straight and level but upside down, (inverted...) your body will experience one negative G, hanging from your seatbelt just as if you were hanging upside down on a playground.  But *upright* it is a far different story... If you experience -1G from a straight and level upright start it means you are accelerating towards the planet at TWICE the rate of a free falling rock!  Your drink would fly up in your face, you would be pulled towards the ceiling and feel like you were hanging upside down.  Anyone not seated and strapped in would be pinned against the top of the cabin by a force equal to their body weight.  Again, this can be sustained for mere seconds before being in very dangerous steep dive and reaching an airspeed that would rip the airframe apart if not corrected.  So, it shouldn’t be hard to see why I challenged your presumption in the question that passengers experience negative G during a descent!

The only time a passenger should experience zero or negative G is very briefly in moderate to severe turbulence.

**Disclaimer:**  There may be some physics majors who will have things to say about my examples.  I welcome your feedback, and will edit my answer to make it better, but the intent is to provide practical and relatable examples, and not turn this into a math lesson...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118186/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-hall-why-do-we-feel-negative-g-forces-in-a-high).

Comment: @Fargan... do you know what the most negative part of this Site is?

Comment: The negatives Gs we experience reading your comments?

Answer (score 1):

What you are calling G-force is not really a force. And, it does not really have anything to do with gravity. It is simply what you feel when you accelerate. It is called G-force due to the fact that it is equal to the amount of acceleration one would experience due to the force of gravity at the Earth’s surface (1G = 9.81 meters per second per second).

Acceleration occurs when an object has a change in the magnitude (amount) of its velocity and/or has a change in the direction of its velocity. If both the amount and the direction of an object’s velocity does not change, and remains steady and constant, there is no acceleration. If there is no acceleration, there is no G-force.

That being said, positive and negative, when it comes to Gs, is subjective and does not truly exist. We just call acceleration upward (relative to us) positive, and acceleration downward (relative to us) negative.

In the same token, when an aircraft banks to turn while keeping its altitude constant, we call it positive Gs even though the G-force is actually to the side, acting laterally and parallel to the Earth. And, an aircraft in a turn is continuously changing direction throughout the entire turn. So, you feel the “positive” Gs throughout the entire turn.

In a climb, you only feel “positive” Gs while the aircraft is accelerating or at the very beginning of the climb. Once the aircraft’s speed and direction have stabilized, you no longer feel “positive” Gs. The same is true in a descent. You just feel Gs in the opposite direction.

To use an analogy with which you might be more familiar, a car does the same thing.

- When a car accelerates, you feel Gs to the back.
- When a car decelerates or stops, you feel Gs to the front.
- When a car goes around a curve or corner, you feel Gs to the side.
- When a car goes down a hill, reaches the bottom, then immediately goes up another hill, you feel “positive” Gs downward.
- When a car reaches and goes over the crest of a hill, you feel “negative” Gs upward.

In the car analogy, you are experiencing Gs even though the car is not pressurized. That is because pressurization has nothing to do with G-forces. And, just like in the car, you would feel similar G-forces in an aircraft regardless of if the cabin is pressurized or not.

Comment: Depending on theory, gravitation might not actually be a force at all.

Comment: @Dean I asked a question from Michael Hall as a comment under his reply above, I want your view as well thanks.

Comment: @Dean as your knowledge in aviation is 100 times more than me, could you help me and say how much steam and at what pressure is required to have 2KN of thrust for 20 seconds? I post it as a new question but was closed and said that not valid question for this forum.Thanks

Comment: @Thomas - Unfortunately not. Firstly, to answer that question several parameters would have to be specified. Secondly, I am not an experts at steam propulsion. You may need to know the size of the orifice or at least the rate of steam through the orifice to get you near an answer. Although, knowing the pressure may get you close. Just remember that F=ma. The mass of the steam would start at 0, then the steam would accelerate to a certain, yet unknown, speed to create the 2 kN of force. Since this is not an aviation question, it might be best posed on SpaceStackExchange.

Comment: @Thomas - By the way, you should probably limit your question here to those involving flight in the atmosphere, aircraft, airports, pilots, and aviation regulation. If you need help for a vehicle that leaves the atmosphere, this probably is not he forum for it. And yes, 30 or 40 kilometers is technically below the Karman Line, it is still above the level of conventional aircraft flight. Then again, traveling at Mach 10 is also beyond conventional flight. And, 2 kN (450 lbs) would not be enough to overcome drag and reach Mach 10 in a passenger aircraft. Even the X-43 is experimental & unmanned.

Comment: @Dean, ok I will never ask any more question. And I wonder from where you brought 10 Mach or those KM altitude, what is that? You may referring my previous comment days ago , if so, it had nothing to do with that. But as I like you I say that what I was looking for here was about a new technology and with most respect to all answers but I should say i failed to be successful here to get what I want.

Comment: @Thomas - I am sorry that you feel that way. Feel free to post as many questions as you like here. Just remember, this forum has protocols. Such as, questions here should not solicit opinions. They should be inquiries seeking actual answers that can be cited and referenced with verifiable facts from reliable sources such as the FAA or EASA. Also, limit the questions to those pertaining to flight, flight dynamics, aerodynamics, aeronautical engineering, piloting, aircraft maintenance, aviation regulations, anything to do with airplanes, etc.